# Segmentation fault as a result of using fgets() to read lines from a file into a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault

I am currently learning C and need a little bit of help with my code.

Say there is a file called "books.txt" that contains the names of several books each on a new line of the file. I am trying to grab the names of each book to use for the rest of my program.

To do this I have created the following struck:

```
struct bookData { // This is my struct to encapsulate book information
     char name[50]; // Name of book
     // Other struct variable
     // Other struct variable
};
```

Now I need to get the names of each book and put them into a struct array. Below is how I've gone about doing so.

```
struct bookData booksList[numBooks]; // numBooks is the number of books in "books.txt"

int i;
for(i = 0; i < numBooks; i++) {
     fgets(booksList[i].name, 50, books);
     // Books is the "books.txt" file that was opened for reading
}
```

When I run this code I encounter a Segmentation fault. I believe the problem lies with the use of the for-loop. However I am not sure how to correct this problem or even why the loop is causing the Segmentation fault to occur. When I simply place the line,

```
fgets(booksList[0].name, 50, books);
```

without the for-loop, no error occurs and the code runs and prints the name of the book just fine.

I am trying to understand why an error is occurring in my code. I would be very grateful if anyone could give me advice on how to fix the error. Thank you in advance for taking the time to read/answer my question!

EDIT: numBooks is essentially the number of lines in the "books.txt" files. Which translates into the number of books for this particular problem. numBooks was calculated with the following code:

```
char c; 
int numBooks; 
while((c = fgetc(books)) != EOF) { 
    if(c == '\n') { 
         numBooks++; 
    } 
}
```

EDIT#2: Thank you everyone for your help!!!

Comment: What is `numBooks`? How is its value retrieved?

Comment: Why not use a debugger and find out which exactly line of code generates the fault?

Comment: If booklist is on the stack and numbooks is large, you can be running out of stackspace somehwere. Alternatively, after your return, the data on the stack is gone but you returned a pointer to it.

Comment: I would print out the value of `numbooks`.  I would also print out each line as you read it in to see how far along you get before you crash.

Comment: You guys were all right! It was a problem with the numBooks. Like Mr. Paul Ogilvie said, the booklist ended up being too big because numBooks was incorrect. Thank you all so much!

Comment: the function: `fgetc()` returns and `int` and the value `EOF` is an `int` (usually equal to -1)  BUT the posted code is assigning to a `char`, so there is the possibility (depends on if `char` is signed or not)` that the EOF will be missed.  What happens if the last line in the file is not terminated with a '\n'?

Comment: this code: `for(i = 0; i < numBooks; i++) {
     fgets(booksList[i].name, 50, books);` is not paying attention to the returned value from `fgets()`  Suggest: `size_t i=0; while( i<numBooks && fgets( bookList[i].name, 50, books ) { i++; }`

Comment: The code should always initialize all local variables before using them, so it starts from a known value.  In the posted code, the variable: `numBooks` is not initialized, so the starting value will be whatever happened to be on the stack at the address of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is erroneous, and could be reasonably expected to cause problems:

```
char c; 
int numBooks; 
while((c = fgetc(books)) != EOF) { 
    if(c == '\n') { 
         numBooks++; 
    } 
}
```

Firstly, `numBooks` is uninitialised, and later use of that is likely to invoke undefined behaviour.

Secondly, though much less likely to cause problems on most systems, `fgetc` returns `int`, which typically has a wider domain (can represent more values than `unsigned char`). This is done for a reason. Any *actual character values* returned by `fgetc` will be as an `unsigned char` (i.e. **positive only**) value. Failure will cause `EOF` (**negative only**). This means `fgetc` could typically return one of 257 values, and by converting straight to `char` you're discarding one of those values: the error-handling one. In other words, you can no longer tell if `fgetc` succeeded or not. What happens when you reach `EOF`? You convert it to a `char`, treat it as a character value (when it isn't) and then try again..? Wrong answer!

In summary, **`fgetc` returns `int`, so store the return value in `int`**...

---

Another problem arises when `numBooks` reaches `INT_MAX`, and `numBooks++;` will cause an overflow. Technically this is undefined behaviour, and could theoretically cause segmentation faults... but I've never personally seen that. Nonetheless, you should probably use an `unsigned` type, as it wouldn't make sense to have a *negative* number of entries in a file, would it?

Come to think about it, if `numBooks` in `struct bookData booksList[numBooks];` were negative (or a large enough number), you might start to see segmentation violations when you access the higher elements.

In summary: **Use an unsigned type when you only expect to see positive numbers, and use dynamic allocation (e.g. `malloc`) for large arrays.**

---

Note that this doesn't cover *all possibilities*, as you haven't provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's not possible/practical to do so; there's a big possibility that your segfault is caused by other code which you've not provided. Please let me know if you update this question, so I can update this answer and keep the world spinning :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough explanation! It really helped me understand what was going on. I printed numBooks and found that it returned an absolutely ridiculous number. (It was 4195735.) I will now work to fix that part of my code.

Comment: Strange number indeed. `INT_MAX` or `UINT_MAX`, perhaps? `INT_MIN` casted to an `unsigned int`, perhaps? Hmmm...

Comment: You forgot the main problem: `numBooks` is not initialized and has automatic storage, That is the reason behind segfault.

Comment: @LPs : You should perhaps post that as an answer. This one addresses a number of minor quality issues unlikely to be causing a problem in this cae and omits this critical error that is certainly the cause.

Comment: I thought the answer was already edited and correct. I will post mine as soon as I will have a laptop with me.

Comment: @LPs Thanks for the extra detail. I missed that! D'oh!